# Google Book Viewer API - can't hide then show

Tags: javascript, google-books

I'm using the Google Book Viewer API to show book previews based on metadata found on the page. This is in a system I don't control, although I can append scripts and markup.

Only some pages contain information about books that have previews available. The book viewer is inside a div which, if the preview isn't found, is empty and looks ridiculous; so my strategy is to hide the div via CSS, then, if a preview is found, change the ID of the div so that it is no longer hidden. If I do that, though, when the div appears, the preview does not show correctly; if you zoom in and out with your browser, it does, but otherwise no.

Here's an example of it working. (I've simplified the script--normally I traverse the page to get the metadata, whereas here I'm just supplying it in a string.) Everything is there except the CSS:
https://googledrive.com/host/0BxoVkXnTNNDoV3NpQUtsNDEyaTQ/gbpreview.htm

And here it is with the CSS, not working:
https://googledrive.com/host/0BxoVkXnTNNDoV3NpQUtsNDEyaTQ/gbpreview2.htm

Anyone know how I might fix this, or can you think of an alternative strategy to achieve what I'm looking for?

And here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">#GoogleBooksPreview {display: none;} </style>
<div id="GoogleBooksPreview">
    <div id="viewerCanvas" style="height: 600px;">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var gbsWidget = document.getElementById('GoogleBooksPreview');
function gbsFound() {
    gbsWidget.id = 'gbsFound';
}
function initialize() {
    var viewer = new google.books.DefaultViewer(document.getElementById('viewerCanvas'), {
        showLinkChrome: false
        });
   viewer.load(['ISBN:9780596805524', 'OCLC:502415271'], null, gbsFound);
    }
    google.load("books", "0");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the recommended way to handle this is to hide the div on failure, rather than unhide the div on success, see [here](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/viewer/developers_guide#Handling_failed_initializations). I'm guessing this is necessary because the viewer needs to know the height of the canvas (which it won't have if the container is hidden).

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/67pay4r2/.

Or without adding a `hidden` class like: http://jsfiddle.net/67pay4r2/1/.

I have added a `hidden` class to the widget div, which is removed when the `initialize` function starts, and then added back if the viewer load fails. This will prevent users with JS disabled from seeing the div.

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you. I think a potential problem for me here is that because it is the script that is adding the "hidden" class, the div (which has some content in addition to the book viewer) will display briefly before hiding itself--this will be awkward on pages that have no match. But I'll see how much of an issue that is.

Comment: Or, sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear: the div that you added the `hidden` class to is not something I can edit--I would need to add that class via JS.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to an example that doesn't add the `hidden` class. So the div is hidden until the `initialize` function unhides it, so that it can calculate canvas height for the viewer. Then it is hidden again if the viewer fails to load. So there is still a chance that there will be a flicker, but I don't know if it is avoidable. I tried some of the hacks [here](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/) for rendering offscreen, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me think it through. As it turns out, I can't use CSS for the initial hide. That's because it won't work unless I add `!important`, and if I do that, then changing it via the script doesn't work. However, I can set it to `display:none` using JS that loads earlier than the GB script, so it seems to work ok, and the flicker when the script unhides itself and then doesn't find a match isn't much of a problem because the widget is sort of far down the page--you have to scroll so you wouldn't get there in time to see the flicker. Thanks again.

Comment: You can override an `!important` css rule by adding an inline style with JS; see here: http://jsfiddle.net/67pay4r2/2/.

Comment: Even better. I've implemented it that way now.